# How to iterate multiple columns after fecthing the records in Soap UI tool

Tags: groovy, soapui

In Soap UI, I am able to connect oracle database using groovy Script.

then I have fetched one record from the table.Now I wanted to know how to Iterate each column present in the row using loop

```
import groovy.sql.Sql;

//Establish JDBC Connection to the DB
def  con = Sql.newInstance(“jdbc:oracle:thin:@<url server database>:<port>:<sid>”, “username”, “password”, “oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver”);

def response = con.rows(“select * from student”)

//storing name in variable
def name = response[0].name.toString()

//setting name record in properties test step
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").setPropertyValue("emp_name",name)

//closing DB Connection
con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest that you use column names instead of select *.
That being said, here is how to iterate rows and get values (I added a column lastName as example):

```
con.eachRow("select name, lastName from student;") { row ->
    def name = row.name
    def lastName = row.lastName

    testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").setPropertyValue("emp_name", name)
    testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").setPropertyValue("emp_last_name", lastName)
}
```

The problem is that you will keep overwriting the properties until just the last one is saved so you have to run the test in the database loop above, like this:

```
def soapTestStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Your SOAP Request").name
testRunner.runTestStepByName(soapTestStep)
```

You can add other actions like working with the response in the loop too:

```
def responseSOAP = context.expand('${Your SOAP Request#Response}')
def responseSection = responseSOAP =~ /whateverNode>(.*)<\/whateverNode/
def responseVal = responseSection[0][1]
log.info "responseVal: ${responseVal}"
```